# Quando pressiono botão play não acontece nada

Tags: android

Não sei qual o motivo que não está funcionando...

RadioPlayer.java

```
package com.example.santanateste;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RadioPlayer extends Activity {

    private ImageButton playButton;    

    private boolean isPlaying;

    private StreamingMediaPlayer audioStreamer;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_main);
        initControls();
    } 

    private void initControls() {

        playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_play);
        playButton.setEnabled(false);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().isPlaying()) {
                {
                    audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().pause();
                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_play);
                }
                } else {
                    audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().start();
                    startStreamingAudio();       
                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_pause);
                }
                isPlaying = !isPlaying;
            }});    
    }

    private void startStreamingAudio() {
        try { 
            if ( audioStreamer != null) {
                audioStreamer.interrupt();
            }
            audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this, playButton);
            audioStreamer.startStreaming("http://www.caikron.com.br:7020", 5208L, 216L);
            //streamButton.setEnabled(false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error starting to stream audio.", e);                    
        }

    }
}
```

StreamingMediaPlayer.java

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * MediaPlayer does not yet support streaming from external URLs so this class provides a pseudo-streaming function
 * by downloading the content incrementally & playing as soon as we get enough audio in our temporary storage.
 */
public class StreamingMediaPlayer {

    private static final int INTIAL_KB_BUFFER =  96*10/8;//assume 96kbps*10secs/8bits per byte

    private ProgressDialog carregando;


    private ImageButton playButton;


    //  Track for display by progressBar
    private long mediaLengthInKb, mediaLengthInSeconds;
    private int totalKbRead = 0;

    // Create Handler to call View updates on the main UI thread.
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private MediaPlayer     mediaPlayer;

    private File downloadingMediaFile; 

    private boolean isInterrupted;

    private Context context;

    private int counter = 0;

     public StreamingMediaPlayer(Context  context, ImageButton    playButton) 
     {
         this.context = context;
        this.playButton = playButton;
        this.carregando = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Conectando...", true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
            {
              public void onCancel(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface)
              {
                StreamingMediaPlayer.this.carregando.dismiss();
                StreamingMediaPlayer.this.interrupt();
              }
            });
            this.carregando.setCancelable(true);
          }

    /**  
     * Progressivly download the media to a temporary location and update the MediaPlayer as new content becomes available.
     */  
    public void startStreaming(final String mediaUrl, long    mediaLengthInKb, long    mediaLengthInSeconds) throws IOException {

        this.mediaLengthInKb = mediaLengthInKb;
        this.mediaLengthInSeconds = mediaLengthInSeconds;

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {   
            public void run() {   
                try {   
                    downloadAudioIncrement(mediaUrl);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to initialize the MediaPlayer for fileUrl=" + mediaUrl, e);
                    return;
                }   
            }   
        };   
        new Thread(r).start();
    }

    /**  
     * Download the url stream to a temporary location and then call the setDataSource  
     * for that local file
     */  
    public void downloadAudioIncrement(String mediaUrl) throws IOException {

        URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();   
        cn.connect();   
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
        if (stream == null) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to create InputStream for mediaUrl:" + mediaUrl);
        }

        downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"downloadingMedia_" + (counter++) + ".dat");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);   
        byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
        int totalBytesRead = 0, incrementalBytesRead = 0;
        do {
            int numread = stream.read(buf);   
            if (numread <= 0)   
                break;   
            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
            totalBytesRead += numread;
            incrementalBytesRead += numread;
            totalKbRead = totalBytesRead/1000;

            testMediaBuffer();
               fireDataLoadUpdate();
        } while (validateNotInterrupted());   

           stream.close();
        if (validateNotInterrupted()) {
               fireDataFullyLoaded();
        }
    }  

    private boolean validateNotInterrupted() {
        if (isInterrupted) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                //mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Test whether we need to transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
     * Interacting with MediaPlayer on non-main UI thread can causes crashes to so perform this using a Handler.
     */  
    private void  testMediaBuffer() {
        Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                    //  Only create the MediaPlayer once we have the minimum buffered data
                    if ( totalKbRead >= INTIAL_KB_BUFFER) {
                        try {
                            startMediaPlayer();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error copying buffered conent.", e);                
                        }
                    }
                } else if ( mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000 ){ 
                    //  NOTE:  The media player has stopped at the end so transfer any existing buffered data
                    //  We test for < 1second of data because the media player can stop when there is still
                    //  a few milliseconds of data left to play
                    transferBufferToMediaPlayer();
                }
            }
        };
        handler.post(updater);
    }

    private void startMediaPlayer() {
        try {   
            File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + (counter++) + ".dat");
            moveFile(downloadingMediaFile,bufferedFile);

            Log.e("Player",bufferedFile.length()+"");
            Log.e("Player",bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            fireDataPreloadComplete();
            this.playButton.setEnabled(true);
            this.carregando.dismiss();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error initializing the MediaPlaer.", e);
            return;
        }   
    }

    /**
     * Transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
     * Interacting with MediaPlayer on non-main UI thread can causes crashes to so perform this using a Handler.
     */  
    private void transferBufferToMediaPlayer() {
        try {
            // First determine if we need to restart the player after transferring data...e.g. perhaps the user pressed pause
            boolean wasPlaying = mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
            int curPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            mediaPlayer.pause();

            File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + (counter++) + ".dat");
            //FileUtils.copyFile(downloadingMediaFile,bufferedFile);

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            //mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioSystem.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(curPosition);

            //  Restart if at end of prior beuffered content or mediaPlayer was previously playing.  
            //    NOTE:  We test for < 1second of data because the media player can stop when there is still
            //  a few milliseconds of data left to play
            boolean atEndOfFile = mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000;
            if (wasPlaying || atEndOfFile){
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error updating to newly loaded content.", e);                    
        }
    }

    private void fireDataLoadUpdate() {
        Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            }
        };
        handler.post(updater);
    }

    /**
     * We have preloaded enough content and started the MediaPlayer so update the buttons & progress meters.
     */
    private void fireDataPreloadComplete() {
        Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                //streamButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        };
        handler.post(updater);
    }

    private void fireDataFullyLoaded() {
        Runnable updater = new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                   transferBufferToMediaPlayer();
            }
        };
        handler.post(updater);
    }

    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return mediaPlayer;
    }

    public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
        }
    }    

    public void interrupt() {
        playButton.setEnabled(false);
        isInterrupted = true;
        validateNotInterrupted();
    }

    public void moveFile(File    oldLocation, File    newLocation)
    throws IOException {

        if ( oldLocation.exists( )) {
            BufferedInputStream  reader = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(oldLocation) );
            BufferedOutputStream  writer = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(newLocation, false));
            try {
                byte[]  buff = new byte[8192];
                int numChars;
                while ( (numChars = reader.read(  buff, 0, buff.length ) ) != -1) {
                    writer.write( buff, 0, numChars );
                  }
            } catch( IOException ex ) {
                throw new IOException("IOException when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if ( reader != null ){
                        writer.close();
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch( IOException ex ){
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Error closing files when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() ); 
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Old location does not exist when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Na inicialização da sua `Activity` chama o método `setEnabled(false)`, o que inibi a ação do botão. Em algum outro momento você chama `setEnabled(true)`?

Comment: não aí...
o problema é que se eu tirar ele fica como ponteiro nulo.

Comment: Eu vi que você habilita o botão no método `startMediaPlayer`, mas como você desabilitou no `onCreate`, não tem como ele iniciar o `streaming` chamado no `onClick`. E não fica nulo se tirar o `setEnabled(false)`, só fica nulo se não pegar ele do Layout (com `playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_play);`);

Comment: Ok, pode me demonstar como ficaria arrumado?

Answer (score 1):

Como o botão foi desabilitado, ele não notifica sobre eventos ao `View.OnClickListener`.
Bastando remover o `setEnabled(false)` na inicialização do seu botão:

```
private void initControls() {
    playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_play);
    // Remove essa linha para nao desabilitar o botao
    //playButton.setEnabled(false);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(audioStreamer == null) {
                startStreamingAudio();
                playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_pause);
            } else if(! audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().isPlaying()) {
                audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().start();
                playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_pause);
            } else {
                audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().pause();
                playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_play);
            }

            isPlaying = !isPlaying;
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: valeu, vou testar.

Comment: aparece isso no log cat:java.lang.NullPointerException, pode ser que outra parte esteja indisponibilizando tbm.

Comment: O `NullPointerException` é porque não inicializou o `audioStreamer', vou incluir em minha resposta.

Comment: mas como eu tiro isso? pois ele para na hora que eu clico no botão.
pois nao toca

Comment: Ainda fiquei na dúvida, você faz o `getMediaPlayer` logo depois, mas o objeto `MediaPlayer` só instanciado quando você começa a baixar o `streaming`, não sei se vai funcionar nessa ordem.

Comment: e trava saindo do app:https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/1897910_712322322178651_336054465756123350_n.jpg?oh=14d4f16578361f8eea930cd1f8f23390&oe=54CF9088&__gda__=1421557385_fe6df6f392ae7b16ebb11708faf5aaa0

Comment: @KauanKubaski, verifique agora. Não entendi quando você começa o `streaming` pela primeira vez. Quando clicar no botão ou automaticamente?

Comment: qdo clicar no botão

Comment: @KauanKubaski, atualizei o código. Se ainda tiver algum problema me avisa, que ai eu revejo a lógica inteira.

Comment: tentei usar essa última atualização, porém o app para completamente quando aperta o play. A ideia é que quando pressionado o button Play - imagem play, ele funcione o startStreamingAudio, ou caso contrário o MediaPlayer pare de funcionar, qdo clicado no pause.